# How to view website launched in Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have followed the [steps provided by Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/EC2Win_CreateWordPressBlog.html). I have installed a wordpress website in the EC2 Instance.

My public DNS is given as ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
and Public IP is also given as xx-xxx-xx-xxx.

How to view the website from any other machine?

Note:

1. EC2 Instance is created and running now.
2. I can view it in the localhost as well as public DNS in the EC2 instance using RDP. (`http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can see the web site from the EC2 instance, but not from other machines, there is probably one of the following things wrong:

1. The DNS entry is not available or is wrong. Since you can RDP using that entry, this can't be the cause.
2. Access to the correct port is being blocked by the security group or firewall. Since the instructions you referenced specifically say to make sure that both port 80 (HTTP) and 3389 (RDP) are open, and you know that is true from port 3389, this isn't likely, but is possible. Make sure that there are security group rules for both port numbers that look the same.
3. The Windows server itself is refusing to allow outside access to port 80 on that address. This is unlikely, but not impossible, and the instructions specify that you should "disable Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration", and at the end cover "Making Your WordPress Site Public". Make sure that the web server isn't configured to only respond to requests from localhost (127.0.0.1) and that there are no Windows firewall rules blocking port 80.

I think that the likeliest problem is number 2, above. Perhaps you forgot to open port 80 in the security group, or typed a different port number or a different address range to open it to.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Obviously problem with the security groups. I have added the 80 for Inbound but forget to apply rule changes :(

Comment: I have the same Issue . Was the firewall.