# Connecting to web app running on localhost on an Amazon EC2 from another computer

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, flask, web, localhost

currently I am working on a web app development and I am running my server on an Amazon ec2 instance. I am testing my (web app which uses Flask) by running the server on localhost:5000 as usual. However I don't have access to the gui hence I don't see my app and test it like I would do on a browser. I have a Mac OS X computer so my question is how can I see the localhost of Amazon EC2 from my mac's browser ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161253/how-to-view-website-launched-in-amazon-ec2-instance)?

Comment: How could you be on the same network as your EC2 instance? Are you inside Amazon's data center?

Comment: Whoops, I meant some other thing. Anyways I updated the question.

Answer (score 16):

You need to tell the Flask Dev webserver to run on `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`.

You specify this option when calling the `.run()` function:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=5000)
```

If you then send a request to the Public IP of your EC2 instance on port 5000 you will reach your Flask Dev webserver.

eg: `http://EC2_IP:5000/`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: you likely need to create a security group setting and then apply it to the ec2 instance for this to work.  also if you are running this from the terminal, type flask run --help to get acquainted or flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000

Answer (score 2):

You cannot connect to localhost on a remote machine *without* a proxy. If you want to test it you will need to change the binding to the public IP address or `0.0.0.0`.

You will then have to lock down access to your own IP address through the security settings in AWS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this format as a URL in your browser to access the ports from the internet -
**instance's public IP / Public IPv4 DNS:port no.**

**example:** 54.145.48.126:5000 **or** ec2-54-145-48-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5000

**Prerequisites:**

You must have added a custom TCP rule to allow access to that port (your case 5000)

[image: Custom TCP rule example]